# Why does ChatGPT have a consistent paragraph length?

Tags: chatgpt

I've noticed that when ChatGPT writes multiple paragraphs, the paragraphs have consistent lengths of roughly 200 characters. Often more than 100, and less than 400. I'm not sure if this is just a result of of the specific prompts that have been feeding the responses (I've been hunting ChatGPT answers on Stack Overflow). Why is ChatGPT like this? Did it learn this behaviour from a specific source / form of writing such as newspapers? (I've heard they have paragraph-length constraints)

Please make your best effort to support your answer with relevant facts and references.

Comment: off-topic as about inner workings?

Comment: concerning the topicality of this question, see also the meta discussion [here](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21/33)

Answer (score 2):

After pre-training on large amounts of Internet data (which would contain a wide range of paragrpah lengths), ChatGPT was fine-tuned on conversational and instruction-following data from human labellers:

> We trained this model using Reinforcement Learning from Human Feedback (RLHF), using the same methods as InstructGPT, but with slight differences in the data collection setup. We trained an initial model using supervised fine-tuning: human AI trainers provided conversations in which they played both sides—the user and an AI assistant. We gave the trainers access to model-written suggestions to help them compose their responses. We mixed this new dialogue dataset with the InstructGPT dataset, which we transformed into a dialogue format.

(source: [Introducing ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt))

Labeller demonstration example, used to teach the model how it should reply:

> ### Prompt:
>
> ELI5: What's the cause of the "anxiety lump" in our chest during stressful or disheartening experiences?
>
> ### Labeler demonstration
>
> The anxiety lump in your throat is caused by muscular tension keeping your glottis dilated to maximize airflow. The clenched chest or heartache feeling is caused by the vagus nerve which tells the organs to pump blood faster, stop digesting, and produce adrenaline and cortisol.

To my knowledge this data and the instructions given for this stage have not been released, but the [InstructGPT paper](https://cdn.openai.com/papers/Training_language_models_to_follow_instructions_with_human_feedback.pdf) does give a table of demo lengths:

| Prompt source | Measurement | Count | Mean | Std | Min | 25% | 50% | 75% | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Contractor | prompt length | 12845 | 437 | 441 | 5 | 42 | 324 | 673 | 2048 |
| Contractor | demo length | 12845 | 38 | 76 | 1 | 9 | 18 | 41 | 2048 |
| Customer | prompt length | 1533 | 153 | 232 | 1 | 19 | 67 | 186 | 1937 |
| Customer | demo length | 1533 | 88 | 179 | 0 | 15 | 39 | 88 | 2048 |

This is measured in tokens, which are [approximately 4 characters](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-long-is-a-token/35#35), so works out to be a mean of 152 characters for the contractor demos and 352 for the customer demos.

Not all demos will be a single paragraph, but I'd speculate that this may be where the tendancy came from — possibly originating in instructions given to labellers on how to phrase replies.

Answer (score -1):

ChatGPT is trained by vast amount of data from the internet [as stated by OpenAI](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6783457-what-is-chatgpt)

> Why does the AI seem so real and lifelike?
>
> These models were trained on vast amounts of data from the internet
> written by humans, including conversations, so the responses it
> provides may sound human-like. It is important to keep in mind that
> this is a direct result of the system's design (i.e. maximizing the
> similarity between outputs and the dataset the models were trained on)
> and that such outputs may be inaccurate, untruthful, and otherwise
> misleading at times.

and other websites; for example, [this](https://www.paperpal.com/blog/news-updates/what-is-chatgpt-and-how-was-it-trained/). So, ChatGPT is likely to have learnt how to write paragraphs like how humans do, more or less. Let's see how humans write *good* paragraphs. There are many articles about how to write paragraphs but I will just give some examples:

- [The Ultimate Guide to Paragraphs](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/paragraphs/#:%7E:text=How%20long%20should%20a%20paragraph,to%20present%20all%20your%20evidence.) by Grammarly
- [How Long Is a Paragraph?](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/how-long-is-a-paragraph/) by Grammarly
- [Paragraph Length: Data from 9,830 Research Papers](https://quantifyinghealth.com/paragraph-length-in-research-papers/) by QuantifyingHealth

The rough average of characters per paragraph is around 100 characters to 200 characters, or around 3 sentences to 5 sentences.

Therefore, ChatGPT tends to write paragraphs around the numbers that mimics humans writing style.

Comment: If it learned from the entire(ish) internet, why focus on grammar sites? Wouldn't e.g. learning from Twitter push it toward very short responses? I think a better answer would look for statistics on human writing more broadly (though that would still have caveats). I wonder whether the RLHF step has more impact?

Comment: This answer is speculation, but you've written it like a logical argument. Your conclusion might be reasonable, but it doesn't _follow_.

Comment: Don't have proof, but I agree the RLHF step is a huge contributor to this. Remember that most LLM if not all are never self-supervised, and always get through a "correction" stage, where it is either fine-tuned or get through a human supervised step (such as RLHF). Without this, I wouldn't be surprised if the output looks somewhat like a normal RNN (in term of usability and coherence). (remainder that this is just my personal observation) @BenReiniger