# How long is a "token"?

Tags: llm, token

LLM max prompt length (e.g: [GPT-4](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-4)) and generation pricing (e.g: [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/cognitive-services/openai-service/)) are both measured by the number of "tokens".

How long is a "token"? Is it equivalent to a single character/letter?

Comment: [tag:text] looks to be me to be a meta-tag. I will suggest replacing it with tags [tag:llm] and [tag:token].

Comment: what models specifically is this question about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A token is commonly around 4 characters:

- OpenAI (GPT) has an interactive tokeniser for GPT-3 and Codex [here](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer) and [claims a token is approximately 4 characters or 3/4ths of a word](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them)
- Anthropic (Claude) also claims [a token is approximately 3/4ths of a word](https://www.anthropic.com/index/100k-context-windows)
- Google (PaLM 2) claims that [a token is equivalent to about 4 characters, and 100 tokens are about 60-80 English words](https://developers.generativeai.google/models/language#model_metadata)
- Meta (LLaMA 2) reportedly has similar with ["roughly 4 characters"](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-machine-learning-blog/introducing-llama-2-on-azure/ba-p/3881233) per token

The exact length will depend on the tokeniser - which splits the input prompt up into a sequence of integers to be read by the model - and also the contents of the text. LLMs commonly use [byte pair encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_pair_encoding) for tokenisation, which causes more common words to have their own token whereas rarer words may be made up of multiple tokens representing pieces of the word.

Comment: It might be relevant to briefly explain "token", "tokenizer", "tokenization"

Comment: Token length is also different for different languages

Comment: @zh., and different models.  An English-focused model might make each Arabic letter a separate token, while a multilingual one might have Arabic word fragments as tokens.