# Does the length of a token give LLMs a preference for words of certain lengths?

Tags: llm, token

From the question [How long is a "token"?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/34/26) we learn that tokens are commonly around 4 characters.  So it seems plausible that LLMs might therefore prefer to have word boundaries coincide with token boundaries.  E.g. maybe ChatGPT, say, has a bias towards (4n-1)-character words (-1 for a whitespace character).

**Question**: Does the length of a token give LLMs a preference for words of certain lengths?

I didn't find the answer by [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=Does+the+length+of+a+token+give+LLMs+a+preference+for+words+of+certain+lengths%3F); I asked [Koala.sh](https://koala.sh/chat) and it said *Language models do not have a preference for words of certain lengths*, and [Assistant](https://poe.com/Assistant) said *Language models like GPT-3.5, which is based on transformer architecture, do not inherently have a preference for words of certain lengths*.  However, neither AI explained their reasoning; I wonder if there's an inherent reason for this, or research into this topic.

(Note this question is *not* about Google, Koala.sh, nor Assistant in particular; I'm just showing my attempts at finding an answer myself, as is generally expected when writing questions.)

Comment: What do you mean by "prefer"?

Comment: The LLM doesn't "know" the length of a token, so it cannot consider or even prefer it. All it knows and works with is its embedding - a fixed-size vector of floats, encoding lots of information about the token, but not its length.

Comment: Maybe this is a topic for meta, but I'm generally opposed to the trend of "Asking the question to various AI tools and trusting what they say", both in questions and *especially* as answers on this site. I don't ask my tarot cards what they think of SE questions, and on uncommon questions (the type that would require more research than a cursory google) I think an LLM and my tarot deck are ~equally accurate and trustworthy (that is, no better than random chance)

Answer (score 3):

> So it seems plausible that LLMs might therefore prefer to have word boundaries coincide with token boundaries. E.g. maybe ChatGPT, say, has a bias towards (4n-1)-character words (-1 for a whitespace character).

Tokens are around 4 characters on average across enough text, but not strictly 4 characters each. Tokenisation will usually give common words their own token - whereas rarer/longer/more-splittable words may be composed of multiple.

Example of the previous sentence in [OpenAI's GPT-3 Tokeniser](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer):
[image]

The model won't be directly aware of how many characters are in each token, although may pick it up from context in the training data.

---

As a rough empirical check, I downloaded [a dataset of ShareGPT conversations](https://huggingface.co/datasets/ar852/scraped-chatgpt-conversations/blob/main/sharegpt_scraped_convs.json), filtered to only ASCII data, and compared bot messages to user messages:

[image]
(62060295 total bot words, 15193352 total user words)

User messages won't be a perfect fit for all the data that GPT-3.5 was trained on, but I don't see any particular pattern above in the bot's character length preference.

Comment: (Note that the GPT-3 Tokeniser isn't the one used by ChatGPT.  Someone made an equivalent here https://foxabilo.com/tokenizer)